# Xpath Query in c++

Tags: c++

I need a xpath query in C++ to get the `idNumber` directly from the node `<revisions>`. I tried the following and it always returns `null`. 
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**xml File:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<cw:vessel version="1.07.0075" creationDate="2016-01-26" xmlns:cw="urn:container">
    <!-- saved from url=(0024)http://www.systemsoftsol.com/ -->
    <Exchanger>
        <revisions>
            <revision>
               <idNumber>1401889476</idNumber>
               <revNumber>0</revNumber>
               <revDate>2014-06-04</revDate>
               <operator>devin</operator>
               <notes>read me</notes>
            </revision>
        </revisions>
  </Exchanger>
</cw:vessel>
```

My code so far:

```
void GetProperties()
{
    HRESULT                         hr = NOERROR;
    CComPtr<::IXMLDOMDocument3>     m_pxmlDomDocument = NULL;
    CComPtr<::IXMLDOMNode>          pNode = NULL;
    IXMLDOMNodeList*                pChildlist = NULL;
    VARIANT_BOOL                    vLoadBool = VARIANT_FALSE;
    hr = m_pxmlDomDocument.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument60));
    hr = m_pxmlDomDocument->setProperty(BSTR(L"SelectionLanguage"), (CComVariant)L"XPath");
    hr = m_pxmlDomDocument->setProperty((CComBSTR)"MaxElementDepth", (CComVariant)INT_MAX);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        hr = ERROR_XML_PARSE_ERROR;
    }
    CComVariant varXmlFileName(_T("xmlfileinput"));
    m_pxmlDomDocument->load(varXmlFileName, &vLoadBool);
    hr = m_pxmlDomDocument->get_documentElement(&pDocRoot);
    hr = pDocRoot->selectSingleNode(_T("//Exchanger"), &pNode);
    pNode->get_childNodes(&pChildlist);
    long size;
    hr = pChildlist->get_length(&size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        CComPtr<::IXMLDOMNode> referNode;
        hr = pChildlist->get_item(i, &referNode);
        if (referNode != NULL)
        {
            CString         csXPathQuery;
            csXPathQuery.Append(_T("/idNumber"));// i need this from above xml
            CComBSTR                    csBstrQuery(csXPathQuery);
            CComPtr<::IXMLDOMNode> pPa;
            hr = referNode->selectSingleNode(csBstrQuery.m_str, &pPa);
        }
    }
}
```

`selectSingleNode()` returns `null` in the above piece of code even though I still have the `idNumber` in the xml file.

Comment: This is comment is not anwser is more like giving alternative: did you consider using libxml/libxml++? I'll give you more easy interfance to xpath. Also you should consider using tinyxml. I think those alternative are far better than msxml + mfc, you know..memory leaks, stuff..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the ans. my self and here is the fix.

1) In selectSingleNode we should pass the idNumber as "//idNumber" instead "/idNumber".

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this code:

```
hr = pDocRoot->selectSingleNode(_T("//Exchanger"),&pNode);
```

The idNumber is not a child of `Exchanger` but a child of `revision`:

```
hr = pDocRoot->selectSingleNode(_T("//Exchanger/revisions/revision"),&pNode);
```

BTW, do you really need to loop over all children of `revision`?
Why can't you ask directly the `idNumber` like this:

```
hr = pDocRoot->selectSingleNode(_T("//Exchanger/revisions/revision/idNumber"),&pNode);
if (pNode != NULL)
{
 // do something
}
```

Comment: In the above simple xml code snippet we know where the idNumber lies. But there may be a chance there are nested nodes inside the node also and tat time i cant hard code the query as you mentioned.

In Exchanger node there may be like 10 other nodes and in all the nodes we have idNumber and i want to get the idNumber from each node one at a time.

Thats why i am looping the exchanger node and giving an xpath on each of the node under Exchanger node.

Comment: No, as I've wrote, I find you don't have idNumber in the "Exchanger" node but in the "revision" node - that is the difference!